# nested fetch with array in second url

Tags: javascript, promise, nested, fetch

I have a nested fetch where the second url should take a value (from an array) from the first result data. The thing is that I need to run the second url for each instance of the array:

```
  fetch(searchUrl)
   .then(function (response) {
       return response.json()
   })
   .then(function (data) {
       searchLoader.style.display = "none";
       for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           let stock = `${data[i].name}, (${data[i].symbol})`
           listOfStocks.innerHTML += `<li class="list-group-item"><a href="./company.html?symbol=${data[i].symbol}">${stock}<a/></li>`
           // console.log(data[i].symbol)
       }
       return fetch(`https://stock-exchange-dot-full-stack-course-services.ew.r.appspot.com/api/v3/company/profile/${data[i].symbol}`)
   })
   .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response)
       return response.json();
   })
   .then(function (data1) {
       console.log(data1);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
       console.log('Requestfailed', error)
   });
});
```

i tried putting the

```
return fetch(`https://stock-exchange-dot-full-stack-course-services.ew.r.appspot.com/api/v3/company/profile/${data[i].symbol}`)
```

in a loop, but of course that didnt work. i also tried to put the second fetch in the initial loop, but also didnt work...

thank you

Comment: Have you tried Promise.all?

Comment: The second fetch isn't even in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all) like this:

```
fetch(searchUrl)
.then(function (response) {
  return response.json()
})
.then(function (data) {
  searchLoader.style.display = "none";
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let stock = `${data[i].name}, (${data[i].symbol})`
      listOfStocks.innerHTML += `<li class="list-group-item"><a href="./company.html?symbol=${data[i].symbol}">${stock}<a/></li>`
      // console.log(data[i].symbol)
  }
  return Promise.all(data.map(item => fetch(`https://stock-exchange-dot-full-stack-course-services.ew.r.appspot.com/api/v3/company/profile/${item.symbol}`)));
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
  return Promise.all(response.map(x => x.json()));
})
.then(function (data1) {
  console.log(data1);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log('Requestfailed', error)
});
```